# How to get a different link dynamically for each option tag value?

Tags: html, tags, html-select

I am creating a form through which customers can purchase an online service.
The form contains a dropdown list with a 'select' & 'option' tag.
The dropdown list is created to choose a billing cycle (6 months, 1 year, 2 years, 3 years)
I want to send the user to different addresses depending on the selection of a billing cycle.

For example:

- If 6 months is selected and "Order now" is clicked, the customer will be send to link 1.
- If 1 year is selected and "Order now" is clicked, the customer will be send to link 2.
- If 2 years is selected and "Order now" is clicked, the customer will be sent to link 3.

I want to change the value of the href attribute dynamically for the ORDER NOW button for each billing cycle.
How to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try following script.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="selProduct">
    <option value=1>6 mths</option>
    <option value=2>1 yr</option>
</select>

<input type=button value="Order Now" id="btnOrder" />

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btnOrder').click(function(){
        if( $('#selProduct').val() == '1')
            window.location='http://msn.com';
        if( $('#selProduct').val() == '2')
            window.location='http://yahoo.com';
    });
 });


</script>

</body>    
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment below you have 3 forms, sorry I was not made aware of this as your question does not state that there is more than one so I have updated my answer, see below.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var order = function() {
       //Check which option was selected for product_1 and re-direct
       if (document.getElementById("product_1").value == "6 months"){ document.getElementById("product_1").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product1_6months.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_1").value == "1 year"){ document.getElementById("product_1").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product1_1year','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_1").value == "2 year"){ document.getElementById("product_1").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product1_2year','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_1").value == "3 year"){ document.getElementById("product_1").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product1_3year','_blank'); }

       //Check which option was selected for product_2 and re-direct
       if (document.getElementById("product_2").value == "6 months"){ document.getElementById("product_2").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product2_6months.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_2").value == "1 year"){ document.getElementById("product_2").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product2_1year.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_2").value == "2 year"){ document.getElementById("product_2").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product2_2year.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_2").value == "3 year"){ document.getElementById("product_2").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product2_3year.php','_blank'); }

       //Check which option was selected for product_3 and re-direct
       if (document.getElementById("product_3").value == "6 months"){ document.getElementById("product_3").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product3_6months.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_3").value == "1 year"){ document.getElementById("product_3").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product3_1year.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_3").value == "2 year"){ document.getElementById("product_3").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product3_2year.php','_blank'); }
       if (document.getElementById("product_3").value == "3 year"){ document.getElementById("product_3").value = "Select"; window.location.replace('product3_3year.php','_blank'); }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" name="product_1">
<select id="product_1">
    <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="6 months">6 months</option>
    <option value="1 year">1 year</option>
    <option value="2 year">2 year</option>
    <option value="3 year">3 year</option>
</select>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="producs_2">
<select id="product_2">
    <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="6 months">6 months</option>
    <option value="1 year">1 year</option>
    <option value="2 year">2 year</option>
    <option value="3 year">3 year</option>
</select>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="product_3">
<select id="product_3">
    <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
    <option value="6 months">6 months</option>
    <option value="1 year">1 year</option>
    <option value="2 year">2 year</option>
    <option value="3 year">3 year</option>
</select>
</form>

<input name="order" type="button" value="Order Now" onClick="order()">
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/Bu2YU/)

Comment: Thanks Malcolm,

this code is working fine but the issue is, I've 3 forms in the same page for three different products so this code is only working for the 1st form.

Please suggest some suitable answer.

Comment: @Andi I have updated my answer to include 3 forms, I hope it is of some help to you.